# how to avoid inline code in .aspx .ascx

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol (.ascx) like this:

```
<% if (HasAccessMediaPlans) { iPortletCounter++; %>
                <div class="orange-portlet-box">
                    <div class="HomeModulePortletTitle"><a href="<%= (RawHtml)RootPath %>MediaPlanning/Default.aspx">Plans</a></div>
                    <p>Create // Edit // Review</p>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<% } %>
```

where HasAccessMediaPlans is a variable defined in user control's code behind(.ascx.cs) and it's assigned in page load.

```
protected Boolean HasAccessMediaPlans = false;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            HasAccessMediaPlans      = SessionState.CurrentUser.HasModuleAccess(MediaString + " Plans");
}
```

My question is: how can I avoid inline server code embeded in <%  %> at my usercontrol markup(.ascx) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap this piece of code with a server side container control (say `<div id="wrapper" runat="server">`) and on the server side assign its visibility properties in the wanted manner.

This avoids littering your `.aspx`/`.ascx` files with code and keeps code in the code-behind file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="orange-portlet-box" id="dvBox" runat="server">
  <div class="HomeModulePortletTitle">
    <a id="aLink">Plans</a>
  </div>
  <p>Create // Edit // Review</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

In code behind

```
Boolean HasAccessMediaPlans = false;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  HasAccessMediaPlans = SessionState.CurrentUser.HasModuleAccess(MediaString + "Plans"); 
  dvBox.Visible = HasAccessMediaPlans;
  aLink.HREF = RootPath + "MediaPlanning/Default.aspx";
}
```